# Relaunch specific activity from middle of the stack again by closing all activities above (including specific one)

Tags: android, launchmode

I have activity stack

`A>B>C>D>E>F`

From `Αctivity` F I want to start `Αctivity` C again from fresh and close all C,D,E,F activities so the new `Αctivity` stack will be:

`A>B>C`(C as a Fresh activity)

I tried using `singleTask` to `Activity` C but it is not relaunching the `Activity` C. It is resuming the `Activity` C

Comment: Finish C activity and start C Activity Again

Comment: Not working. It makes the stack A>B>D>E>F>C

Comment: Before you go `C>D>E>F(current activity)` finishes all activity when move to next. Then Go Activity C and finish Activity F then your activity stack should A>B>C

Comment: why would you want to create a new activity and then leave it in the middle of the stack?  You need to preserve code flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am answering my own question. If anyone is facing the same issue you can refer the answer.

As I have researched a lot on the thing I wanted to achieve I came across this is not possible to relaunch the Activity C. So I solved it by adding launchmode singleTask to the Activity C. And from Activity F I am launching the activity C again and performing the task that I want to perform in onNewIntent() the overridden method on activity C.

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult`  to start C, D, E, F Activity

```
  public static void start(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
         context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
```

Call this method while you are finishing F Activity (The place that you want to relaunch C Activity)

```
 public static void finishAct(@NonNull Context context) {
       Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("recreateC", true);
          context.setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            context.finish();
    }
```

In E and D Activty

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 // handle result
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
finishAct(this)
}
}
```

In C Activity

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // handle result
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
      finishAct(this)
      // todo start C Activity again 
    }
  }
```